# Getting "Warning: EPERM, operation not permitted" when using grunt-contrib-copy but file does copy

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I want to copy style.css in the build directory to overwrite the style.css in the main project directory.

This is my file structure

```
project
├── assets
│   ├── styles
│   │  └── build
│   │       └── style.css
│   └── gruntfile.js
└── style.css
```

In my gruntfile.js file I have:

```
copy: {
    dev: {
        files: [{
            cwd: 'styles/build/',
            src: 'style.css',
            dest: '../',
            expand: true
        }]
    }
},
```

When I run grunt, I get this error:

```
Running "copy:dev" (copy) task
Warning: EPERM, operation not permitted '../style.css' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

But it does copy the file. 
I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are incorrect, `../dest` is incorrect also, you have to put your destination in `'.'`.

Try it:

```
copy: {
    dev: {
        files: [{
            cwd: 'assets/styles/build/',
            src: 'style.css',
            dest: '../',
            expand: true
        }]
    }
},
```

If you are using Windows, try to open your CMD as administrator. Maybe you have permission problems with your style.css

Comment: From the file structure I gave, you are correct, but I made a mistake! The gruntfile.js file is in the assets directory, not the project directory. I've made the change to the original question. Sorry about that.

Comment: I am on a mac and permissions are correct for style.css.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not possible to move files in a parent destination. Why don't move your gruntfile to the root folder?

Comment: It is actually copying the file, though. It works, it just gives me that error and aborts afterwards.

Comment: I took your advice and moved gruntfile to the project directory and changed the copy code accordingly, but I get the same error (after again, successfully copying the file).

Comment: Try cleaning the node cache with `npm cache clean`